# Does MongoDB aggregation $project decrease the amount of data to be kept in memory?

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am wondering whether writing `$project` just after the `$match` statement is actually decrease the amount of data to be kept in memory. As an example if we want an array element with paging from a user document like following:

```
const skip = 20;
const limit = 50;

UserModel.aggregate([
            { $match: { _id: userId } },
            { $project: { _id: 0, postList: 1 } },
            { $slice: ["$postList", skip, limit] },
            { $lookup: ...
]);
```

Assume that there are other lists in the user document and they are very large in size.

So, Is `$project` will help to improve the performance by not taking other large lists in memory?

Comment: `$project` doesn't improve / decrease perfomance. It's used to `include`, `exclude` and `transform` data. Only if any document in the result set exceeds 16Mb MongoDB will fail. Take a look [docs says](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#result-size-restrictions)

Comment: So if I will use $project at last stage of pipeline to transform the result and not at the beginning then it will not effect the performance? e.g. if there is a follower list in the users document whose size is 10,000 and I just want to relieve the post list whose size is 100. The aggregation stages are: 1.match the _id 2.populate different fields, in user model like tagged users, using lookup 3.project the post list. Isn't the memory consumption before lookup can be reduced with only projecting post list at 2nd step?

Comment: Imagine MongoDB as `ladle`. You may fill it completely with soup or you may fill it a bit, will you increase / decrease `ladle` performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each aggregation stage scans the input documents from the collection (if its the first stage) or the previous stage. For example,

- match (filters the documents) - this will reduce the number of
  documents, the overall size
- project (transforms or shapes the document) - this can reduce (or
  increase) the size of the document;    the number of documents remain
  same
- group - reduces the number of documents and changes the size
- skip, limt - reduce the number of documents
- sort - no change in the size or number of documents,
  etc.

Each stage can affect the memory or cpu or both.
In general the document size, number of documents, the indexes, and memory can affect the query performance.

The memory restrictions for aggregation are already clearly specified in the documentation (see [Aggregation Pipeline Limits](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/index.html)). If the memory limit exceeds the restrictions the aggregation will terminate. In such cases you can specify the aggregation option `{ allowDiskuse: true }`, and the usage of this option will affect the query performance. If your aggregation is working without any *memory* related issues (like query termination due to exceeding the memory limits) then there is no issue with your query performance directly.

The `$match` and `$sort` stages use indexes, if used early in the pipeline. And this can improve performance.

Adding a stage to a pipeline means extra processing, and it can affect the overall performance. This is because the documents from the previous stage has to pass thru this extra stage. In an aggregation pipeline the documents are passed through each stage - like in a pipe and the stage does some data transformation. If you can avoid a stage it can benefit the overall query performance, sometimes. When the numbers are large, having an extra (unnecessary) stage is definitely a disadvantage. You have to take into consideration both the memory restrictions as well as size and the number of documents.

A `$project` can be used to reduce the size of the document. But, is it necessary to add this stage? It depends on the factors I had mentioned above and your implemetation and the application. The documentataion ([Projection Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#projection-optimization)) says:

> The aggregation pipeline can determine if it requires only a subset of
> the fields in the documents to obtain the results. If so, the pipeline
> will only use those required fields, reducing the amount of data
> passing through the pipeline.

Comment: In my case, only `postList` is used in further pipeline stages after `$match`, so I have added to project only `postList` at 2nd stage. But as you have described (and what my understanding from your description is) that I don't need to do this my self. Pipeline optimisation automatically does this for me. Am I right?

Comment: In this case the match and project coming early in the pipeline is an advantage. The match stage reduces the number of documents to be processed. The project decreases the size of the documents. As it is with both the stages the pipeline is optimized. With your application the projection restricts the fields to one, and it is important (it is required and not an additional stage). The query optimizer _might_ do further optimization (I don't know what it is), as you are also using other stages like skip, limit, etc.